# cannot remove outline from dropdown

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

The bootstrap-vue dropdown menu always opens with a focus outline. I do not know why it is showing up. I tried to remove it by CSS but I don't want to have to remove it manually.

here you can see the outline.

[image: My page]

This is the official page.

[image: Official page]

Edit: there is no additional CSS rule I am applying anywhere.

bootstrap: 4.3.1

bootstrap-vue: 2.0.4

Comment: is the HTML tag the same as it is in the example? Thinking of if you did it with an <a> tag instead of button, there could be an outline for focus/active etc...

Comment: everything is the same as the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using bootstrap `4.4.x`, which `bootstrap-vue` doesn't support yet.

Bootstrap made some changes in  the 4.4.0 release to their reboot css that removed the previous styling that hides the outline from elements with `tabindex="-1"` that the dropdown has.

`bootstrap-vue` will fix this in the upcoming `2.2.0` release, but for now i would advise to use bootstrap `4.3.1` as recommended in the documentation.

**Edit:**
`bootstrap-vue v2.2.0` has been released which fixes these issues.

Comment: I am using 4.3.1. Updated the question.

Comment: @Asadali How did you check what version you are using?

Comment: from package.json

Comment: @Asadali If you have `"bootstrap": "^4.3.1"` in your `package.json` it will still install `v4.4.1`. Instead write `"bootstrap": "4.3.1"` to make sure you use `v4.3.1` - You can read the different syntax's at https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies